Why does the developer's survey banner keep showing up?
Over the last couple of days, I've been seeing the banner that invites me to take the developer's survey even though I already have taken it. What's up with that?

Survey completion is not tied to accounts, so it can't tell if you've taken it or not; this is by design, not a bug.

Yep, me too, Banner + also receiving Emails, pretty annoying... (I didn't clear any Cookies after taking the Survey, maybe 2 weeks ago...) // And @Zoe, hum, I'm not convinced, from this Thread where the User was advised to clear Cookies to be able to go back one page or to take the Survey again...

@chivracq  That's because the survey system likely keeps track, but this information is not conveyed back to SO. My initial statement still holds

@Zoe, clicking on the Banner happens on SO, so of course that gets tracked, and yep we don't get the 'Census' Badge anymore (published publicly at least), but SO still gets the exact same amount of info and pretty well knows who took (and finished) the Survey, like all the years before... => So we don't need to be nagged/spammed with Banner-Popups and Emails again and again... (OK, about Email(s), I think I only received one extra (after completing the Survey, or maybe 2 max).)

@chivracq Yes, but they're doing this intentionally. It isn't a bug. They shouldn't be doing it, but that's a discussion (or an FR at a stretch), not a bug

@Zoe, ja-ja, I completely agree, well I never said there was a Bug anywhere, I just said "Me Too" to OP (now at +17, so I guess we are not the only ones), and that those reminders were a bit annoying... And that SO has (or should have!) the tech-know-how to handle this situation a some "neater" way than they currently do... (Then OP wouldn't have started this Thread, and we wouldn't be having this discussion...)
